# remove duplicated columns in Spark using SQL expression

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I think this question similar to some other questions, but it is not asked.

In Spark, how can we run SQL query with duplicate column removed?

For example, a SQL query running on spark

```
select a.* from a
left outer join
   select b.* from b
on a.id = b.id
```

how can I remove the duplicated column b.id in this case?

I know we can use additional steps in Spark, such as providing alas or rename columns, but is there a faster way to remove the duplicated columns simply by writing SQL querys?

Answer (score 4):

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2 and going to perform join operation on the basis of id column.

```
scala> val df1  = Seq((1,"mahesh"), (2,"shivangi"),(3,"manoj")).toDF("id", "name")
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, name: string]

scala> df1.show
+---+--------+
| id|    name|
+---+--------+
|  1|  mahesh|
|  2|shivangi|
|  3|   manoj|
+---+--------+

scala> val df2  = Seq((1,24), (2,23),(3,24)).toDF("id", "age")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, age: int]

scala> df2.show
+---+---+
| id|age|
+---+---+
|  1| 24|
|  2| 23|
|  3| 24|
+---+---+
```

Here is an incorrect solution, where the join columns are defined as the predicate.

```
df1("id") === df2("id")
```

The incorrect result is that the id column is duplicated in the joined data frame:

```
scala> df1.join(df2, df1("id") === df2("id"), "left").show
+---+--------+---+---+
| id|    name| id|age|
+---+--------+---+---+
|  1|  mahesh|  1| 24|
|  2|shivangi|  2| 23|
|  3|   manoj|  3| 24|
+---+--------+---+---+
```

The correct solution is to define the join columns as an array of strings Seq("id") instead of expression. Then joined dataframe does not have duplicate columns.

```
scala> df1.join(df2, Seq("id"),"left").show
+---+--------+---+
| id|    name|age|
+---+--------+---+
|  1|  mahesh| 24|
|  2|shivangi| 23|
|  3|   manoj| 24|
+---+--------+---+
```

For more information, you can refer from [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/faq/join-two-dataframes-duplicated-column.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since Spark 1.4.0, you can use join in two ways, columns or joinExprs. When using first way, the join columns will only appear once in the output.

```
/**
 * Inner equi-join with another [[DataFrame]] using the given columns.
 *
 * Different from other join functions, the join columns will only appear once in the output,
 * i.e. similar to SQL's `JOIN USING` syntax.
 *
 * {{{
 *   // Joining df1 and df2 using the columns "user_id" and "user_name"
 *   df1.join(df2, Seq("user_id", "user_name"))
 * }}}
 *
 * Note that if you perform a self-join using this function without aliasing the input
 * [[DataFrame]]s, you will NOT be able to reference any columns after the join, since
 * there is no way to disambiguate which side of the join you would like to reference.
 *
 * @param right Right side of the join operation.
 * @param usingColumns Names of the columns to join on. This columns must exist on both sides.
 * @group dfops
 * @since 1.4.0
 */

def join(right: DataFrame, usingColumns: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {
  join(right, usingColumns, "inner")
}
```